# replace string after each second occurence of character

Tags: javascript, regex

Working with a javascript-variable, I want to replace each occurence of a word (in the example: 'OR' with the ||-sign), but only if it does NOT occur in a doublequoted string.

Is it possible using a **regular expression**?

An example of what I'm looking upon:

```
'one OR " two OR " OR three OR five OR " OR six "'.replace( regex , ???) is giving
'one || " two OR " || three || five || " OR six "'
```

I've tried with:

```
regex = new RegExp("([^\"]*)(OR?)([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")" , "gi");
text = text.replace( regex , "$1||$3");
```

result:

```
'one || " two OR " OR three OR five || " OR six "'
```

which leaves me with some ORs to be replaced.

If I try to do the replacement one more time, to get rid of the remaining ORs, the replacement does (of course) not work:

```
'||ne || " two OR " OR three || five || " OR six "'
```

The letter 'o' in 'one' has been replaced with the ||-sign, which wasn't intended!

Is it possible to do with with an regExp?

Comment: I don`t know by regex but you can try split function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKAY you want regex? I will give you regex:

```
var str = 'one OR " two OR " OR three OR five OR " OR six "';
var res = str.replace(/OR/g, '||');
console.log(res.replace(/(.*?)(\".*?)\|\|(.*?\")/g, '$1$2OR$3'));
```

ENJOY MADI !

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to do this with a single regex, I would split up the work:

```
spl = text.split(/(".*?")/);
result = "";
spl.forEach(function (piece) {
    if (~piece.indexOf('"')) {
        result += piece;
    }
    else {
        result += piece.replace("OR", "||");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UkBZF/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was only looking for a regular expression to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
var str = 'one OR " two OR " OR three OR five OR " OR six "'; 
var res = str.replace(/or/gi,"||");
```

This will replace all `or` words case-insensitive.

Comment: Contents in doublequotes should NOT be altered (although see @aelor).

Comment: Right. My Bad. Completely missed that part :(